# Splitting cells within dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV that I read into a dataframe to drop certain columns and do some manipulations.

Some example rows are:

```
20        2/5/1954 13:55          0.5           18
21        2/5/1954 14:35          0.5         18.2
22        2/5/1954 16:35          0.5         18.5
```

I want to drop out the time in the datetime, so that, for example, I get `2/5/1954` instead of `2/5/1954 13:55`.

I wrote this script:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv('habsos_20200310.csv', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# Get only the columns we care about
dfSub = df[['sample_date','sample_depth','water_temp']]

# Remove the NaN values
dfClean = dfSub.dropna()

# Select 0.5 depth measurements only
dfClean2 = dfClean.loc[df['sample_depth'] == '0.5']

print(dfClean2)
```

Which gives me:

```
             sample_date sample_depth   water_temp
20        2/5/1954 13:55          0.5           18
21        2/5/1954 14:35          0.5         18.2
22        2/5/1954 16:35          0.5         18.5
23        2/5/1954 16:52          0.5         18.5
24        2/5/1954 17:10          0.5         18.6
25        2/5/1954 17:25          0.5         18.8
26        2/5/1954 17:43          0.5           19
```

I tried to add these lines to my script to transform the `sample_date` column:

```
new_df = dfClean2['sample_date'].str.split()[0]

print(new_df)
```

But I get this error:

```
$ python3 habsos.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "habsos.py", line 22, in <module>
    new_df = dfClean2['sample_date'].str.split()[0]
  File "/home/reallymemorable/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1071, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/home/reallymemorable/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

How can I modify my script so I get this as an ouput?

```
             sample_date sample_depth   water_temp
20        2/5/1954               0.5           18
21        2/5/1954               0.5         18.2
22        2/5/1954               0.5         18.5
...
```

Comment: you need to add the parameter `expand=True` in the `split(expand=True)` to actually create columns and then the column 0 will be accessible. But if you point is to get the date only, then have a look at `pd.to_datetime(dfClean2['sample_date']).dt.date`

Comment: Thanks!  Changing the split line to `new_df = dfClean2['sample_date'].str.split(expand=True)[0]` indeed returned a column of just the dates.  But how can I get the other columns back again as well when I `print(new_df)`?

Comment: do you want to create a new dataframe or you want this back in the variable `dfClean2`

Comment: I want to replace the original `sample_date` column datetime values with the new, date-only values.  The last codeblock in my post has an example of what I'm seeking.

Comment: try `dfClean2['sample_date'] = dfClean2['sample_date'].str.split(expand=True)[0]`, then dfClean2 should be as expected

Comment: hi there, did you try my solution?

Comment: yes sorry - i just marked it as accepted.  I actually used @Ben.T 's answer to solve the issue, but yours works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments already suggested you use `expand=True`. Another option is

```
dfClean2.sample_date = dfClean2.sample_date.str.split(' ').str.get(0)
```

However, pandas has many methods implemented for dtype `datetime`. I recommend you pass parameter `parse_dates=True` on `.read_csv()` ([handle datetime with read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#datetime-handling)) and use `.dt` series accesor on that column.

```
dfClean2.sample_date = dfClean2.sample_date.dt.date
```

Read more about .dt accessors in the official pandas website:

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#datetimelike-properties)

[User guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors)